# Clearing the listview contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have created here a code that would store the array contents into a listview by pressing a button, my problem is the listview contents would stack. I want to clear the previous listview contents everytime i press the button and be able to display again the updated stored array contents.

```
    <div id="MainPage" data-role="page" >

        <div data-role="content">

            <a href="#ViewPage" data-role="button" onClick="displayArray( )">RENAME</a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="ViewPage" data-role="page" >

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#MainPage" data-role="button" data-icon="back">BACK</a>
            <h1>View Page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="viewlist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Sample Contents" data-inset="true">
                     <!-- array contents goes here -->
            </ul>   
        </div>

    </div>  

    <script>

         var sampleContent = new Array( );

        displayArray( )
        {
        //i want to place a code here that would clear the listview contents
            for(var scan=0; scan<sampleContent.length; detect++)
            {
                 //looping of the array contents into the listview  
                 $('#viewlist').append('<li><a href="#">' + sampleContent[scan] + '</a></li>').listview("refresh");
            }       
        }

    </script>
```

I am stuck with this problem right now, any help or advice will be gladly accepted thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your `sampleContent()` function

Comment: sampleContent is the array i used to store data into the listview. I want to clear the listview within the displayArray( ) function before the for loop. i have tried ('#viewlist').empty( ); but it does not add listview contents anymore after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job. Just add all data then you empty the list and append all the string for a faster result.

```
    displayArray( )
    {
    //i want to place a code here that would clear the listview contents
    var data='';    
    for(var scan=0; scan<sampleContent.length; detect++)
        {
            data+='<li><a href="#">' + sampleContent[scan] + '</a></li>';
        }
     $("#viewlist").empty().append(data);        
    }
```

Comment: this works but the listview design disappears after the second input, second instance of triggering the displayArray() function. Here is a screenshot of my output. http://i.imgur.com/IN7UIOA.jpg

Comment: Just add .listview("refresh") to the end of the last line:$("#viewlist").empty().append(data).listview("refresh");

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked with lists, this is how I went about this:

```
displayArray( )
    {
    //Emptys viewlist
    $('#viewlist').empty();
    //i want to place a code here that would clear the listview contents
        for(var scan=0; scan<sampleContent.length; detect++)
        {
             //looping of the array contents into the listview  
             $('#viewlist').append('<li><a href="#">' + sampleContent[scan] + '</a></li>');
        }  
        //Update list  
        $("#viewlist").listview("refresh");   
    }
```

You have to empty, append then update.